# Adding indicators to arbitrary xts series in quantmod

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I have an xts series, `aa`:

```
> head(aa,5)   
   2007-04-11    2007-04-12    2007-04-13    2007-04-16    2007-04-17    
 0.0047611824  0.0062745179  0.0026487345  0.0003984707 -0.0021724529
```

I can graph it in quantmod:

```
> lineChart(aa, TA=NULL)
```

But I get an error when I try to add an indicator:

```
> addMACD()
Error in dimnames(cd) <- list(as.character(index(x)), colnames(x)) : 
 'dimnames' applied to non-array
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to graph the residuals of an lm() function. Those are xts but also zoo. When I applied as.xts to them, it worked fine. Still not sure why.